# ld.so error requesting libgtk3-nocsd.so.0, but windows get double titlebars if I install it

Tags: gnome, unity, gtk3, titlebar, csd

After foolishly installing multiple desktop environments alongside my Gnome setup, including Xfce, Unity, and Cinnamon, I get an error message in my terminal whenever I execute any command or even open it:

`ERROR: ld.so: object 'libgtk3-nocsd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.`

Pretty sure Unity is the culprit.

I installed `libgtk3-nocsd.so` using Synaptic package manager but I think it gave my Nautilus windows double title bars.  Uninstalling `libgtk3-nocsd0` and `gtk3-nocsd` fixes that but brings back the error.